# Publish scala project to azure feed using sbt: Unable to find credentials for

Tags: azure, scala, azure-devops, sbt

I want to publish my scala project(=multi project) using "stb publish" in my azure devOps Feed Test.
For this purpose I make the settings below as requested.

```
publishTo := {Some("azure" at "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/anyTeam/blub12351234154124/_packaging/Test/maven/v1")}

credentials += Credentials("", "pkgs.dev.azure.com", "Username", "5mctdrtasdasdLongAccesstokenwithManyCharacterscytgcg2hlura")
```

But I always get the message

> Unable to find credentials for
>   [https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/ @
>   pkgs.dev.azure.com]

and logically the authentication fails with

> 401 Unauthorized

I have already tried to follow the advices in the issues https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5492 and https://github.com/sbt/ivy/pull/36 but without result

I also tested the plugin https://github.com/arktekk/sbt-aether-deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (perhaps) you are using cross compiled projects (using [sbt-crossproject](https://github.com/portable-scala/sbt-crossproject)), you'd have to add the credentials to the settings of the project you want to publish like this:

```
lazy val myProject = crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform).in(file("."))
  .settings(
    organization := "com.example",
    name := "my project name",
    credentials += Credentials("", "pkgs.dev.azure.com", "Username", "5mctdrtasdasdLongAccesstokenwithManyCharacterscytgcg2hlura")
    // ...
)
```

Answer (score 6):

I tested different ways to connect to an Azure Artifacts feed using sbt. From all tested combinations, I found exactly one which seems to work. I tested using **sbt v1.3.10**, which is the latest officially released version at the time of writing.

Define sbt version in `build.properties`:

```
sbt.version = 1.3.10
```

Actually using the Azure Artifacts feed in `build.sbt`:

```
// Go back to Apache Ivy for library management.
// Coursier is currently not able to work with Azure Artifacts feeds.
ThisBuild / useCoursier := false

// Specify credentials in a properties file.
// Not 100% sure if I tested hard coded credentials.
// I did test specifying credentials in ~/.m2/settings.xml which did not work
// (but I'm not sure if either Ivy or Coursier are meant to pick them up).
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "azureArtifactsFeed.credentials")

// Specify the resolver using the following syntax.
// I tested creating an Ivy resolver using Resolver.url() with Resolver.mavenStylePatterns
// (thinking we're using Ivy anyways and it seems to support maven repos), but that failed
// as well (again, I'm not 100% sure if that's supposed to work in the first place).
resolvers += "SOME_NAME" at
  "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/FEED_UUID/_packaging/FEED_NAME/maven/v1"

// With the setup so far, we should already be able to consume artifacts.
// Now for the publishing part:
publishTo := Some("SOME_NAME" at
  "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/FEED_UUID/_packaging/FEED_NAME/maven/v1")
```

And last but not least, it's important to keep the realm empty in the properties file for the credentials.

So in `~/.sbt/azureArtifactsFeed.credentials`:

```
realm=
host=pkgs.dev.azure.com
user=ORGANIZATION
password=USER_TOKEN_WITH_PACKAGING_READ_AND_WRITE_SCOPE
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with SBT. Reference: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5492

I was able to make it work using the sbt plugin: https://github.com/arktekk/sbt-aether-deploy

For **JDK8** use (you could try newer version with JDK11)

```
addSbtPlugin("no.arktekk.sbt" % "aether-deploy" % "0.26.0")
```

This is how my `build.sbt` looks:

```
publishMavenStyle := true,
publishTo := {
  val url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/YYY/_packaging/ZZZ/maven/v1/"
  Some("snapshots" at url)
},
credentials += Credentials("", "pkgs.dev.azure.com", "XXXX",
  "YYYYYYY")
```

To publish remotely: `sbt aetherDeploy`